# AngularJS: when to use $apply in a 'scroll' event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that adds 'fixed' class by:

```
ng-class='{ "fixed": fixed }'
```

The directive has the following function:

```
angular.element($window)
  .on('scroll', function() {
    if (this.pageYOffset >= 480) {
      if (!scope.fixed) {
        scope.fixed = true;
        scope.$apply();
      }
    } else {
      if (scope.fixed) {
        scope.fixed = false;
        scope.$apply();
      }
    }
  });
```

My question is, should I apply the `scope.$apply()` like this, so it only fires whenever my variable changes, or is it ok just to write:

```
angular.element($window)
  .on('scroll', function() {
    if (this.pageYOffset >= 480) {
      scope.fixed = true;
    } else {
      scope.fixed = false;
    }
    scope.$apply();
  });
```

Maybe there's some use of `scope.$watch` that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to call `scope.$apply()` if no update is made. So I would suggest use your first approach which is :

```
   angular.element($window)
  .on('scroll', function() {
    if (this.pageYOffset >= 480) {
      if (!scope.fixed) {
        scope.fixed = true;
        scope.$apply();
      }
    } else {
      if (scope.fixed) {
        scope.fixed = false;
        scope.$apply();
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you need run digest cycle manually. When you are modifying scope through an events. using `scope.$apply` that internally call digest cycle & then update all the scope related binding on view.

Simply modifying angular scope outside on Angular context will need to run digest cycle.

> 1. Which Approach is best?

Your 2nd way looks appropriate to me.

> 2. Maybe there's some use of scope.$watch that I am unaware of?

Yes, you can use watch which will perform dirty checking & whenever value gets change it will fire a function. By using watch you don't need to worry about digest cycle.

Adding watch window `pageYOffset` property, instead of using `scroll` event.

**Code**

```
$scope.$watch(function(){ return $window.pageYOffset }, function(newVal, oldVal){
       if (newVal >= 480) {
          scope.fixed = true;
       } else {
          scope.fixed = false;
       }
});
```

Comment: I know I have to run scope.$apply, but I am asking which way of running it is the preferred one?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you don't have to duplicate `scope.$apply()` in every `if-else` branch, so your second example makes more sense. However you can simplify it further:

```
angular.element($window).on('scroll', function () {
    scope.fixed = this.pageYOffset >= 480;
    scope.$apply();
});
```

.. because expression `this.pageYOffset >= 480` already resolves to `true` or `false`.

Comment: Isn't running scope.$apply everytime a user scrolls a bit overkill on performance?

Comment: Yes and very sensitive. I usually implement some throttle mechanism.