# How can I change a scope variable using the on-scroll event in Ionic?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to change value of a variable when the value of scroll position is greater than 100 from top but it doesn't work, the value doesn't change in `$scope`.
Here is the code:

```
 <div ng-show="title===true">
  <p>{{title}}</p>
  <p>{{card.nome}}</p>
  <p>{{card.prezzo}}€</p>
</div>
```

`<ion-content style="top:0px" delegate-handle="cardScroll" on-scroll="getPositionScroll()">`

```
$scope.title = true;
  $scope.getPositionScroll = function () {
    console.log("scrollPosition " + JSON.stringify($ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('cardScroll').getScrollPosition().top));
    console.log("valore title " + $scope.title);
    console.log($ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('cardScroll').getScrollPosition().top >= 100);
    $scope.title = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('cardScroll').getScrollPosition().top >= 100;
  };
```

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Comment: any error in the console

Comment: no there is no error. I print the value of title and in console the value change but not in the html.And ng-show is always true.

Comment: if the value in the console changes then definitely the new scrolled value is there. what is the issue then?

Comment: But ng-show doesn't change value even if in console title is false and i don't know why. I tried also with $scope.watch but it not trigger.

Comment: put up break point and check if it is reaching that line

Comment: the line is reached because it prints the value in console

Answer (score 0):

I think it may have to do with the fact that Angular doesn't track changes that have been made by the `getPositionScroll()` function. A lot of Angular functions are wrapped in the `$scope.$apply()` function which notifies Angular about changes that have been made. But I think that the function used to track scrolling is not wrapped in this function, which means that you need to call it yourself.

So after `$scope.title` add:

```
$scope.$apply($scope.title);
```

There are a lot of questions regarding when to use `$scope.$apply()`, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817111/when-is-it-safe-to-use-scope-apply), if overused it can cause serious harm to the performance of your app. There is also information about this in the [Angular documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()). You may also find some insight in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212597/angularjs-when-to-use-apply-in-a-scroll-event) about when to use this function in a scroll event.

Comment: I tried your solution and it works fine, thanks a lot.